# ELK querying with python - Multiple conditions

Tags: python, elk, querying

I am trying to query the ELK using the following query:

```
query = {
      "query": {
        "match" : { "event.action" : "ssh_login" },
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-2d/d",
            "lt": "now/d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But i get the following error:

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')
```

I want all the samples where `"event.action"` is equal to `"ssh_login"` and i also want to get a specific time window. What is the correct format for the above query? Also i am having problem with specifying the timestamp. The format of the timestamp is `[2021-07-14T05:24:07.000Z]`, how can i use specific timestamps for querying?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's better to provide more context at least including the following:

- ES version
- Python version
- Elasticsearch python client version
- index mapping

That said, I'll make some assumptions and move on.

- ES : 7.14.0
- Python : 3.7.7
- Elasticsearch Python client : 7.14.1

1. Query

You have to use `bool` query to have multiple queries/conditions to find relevant documents.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

body = {
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [
        {'term': {'event.action': {'value': 'ssh_login'}}},
        {'range': {'timestamp': {'gte': '2020-01-01T01:01:01.000Z'}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
es.search(index="YOUR INDEX NAME", body=body)
```

2. Timestamp

This depends on your mapping. In my example, I used the following mapping.

```
{
  'test': {
    'mappings': {
      'properties': {
        'event': {
          'properties': {
            'action': {
              'type': 'keyword'
            }
          }
        },  
        'timestamp': {
          'type': 'date'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you specified custom dateformat that is not compatible with the format you are trying to query with, it might raise an error.